# UWP App Crashes without an exception when given large amount of data

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app

Crash takes place in this [page](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/AlbumsPage.xaml.cs).

Although I wasn't given an exception, I believe it should be the `Setup` function that causes the crash.

It works fine when the parameter `songs` has about 300 items (I haven't tested for the max yet).

However, it crashes when there are 800 or more items (I also haven't tested for the min yet), that would make me have a lot of `AlbumView`s, whose constructor is defined [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Models/AlbumView.cs).

In its constructor, it finds and sets `Cover` (which comes from `StorageItemThumbnail`) asynchronously. And I believe finding a thumbnail is an IO operation. It might be the frequent IO operations that causes the crash. But I am not sure about it.

Can someone give me some advice on how to fix the crash?

The data source of `songs` comes from the music files in a folder on my computer. I have grouped them in sub-folders, and my app works fine for individual sub-folders. It crashes when I use the root folder of all my music files, which has about 2800 files.

---Update---

I just confirmed that the crash was caused by frequent IO by commenting out the function `FindThumbnail`.

So I try to fix it by using the lazy load strategy. I first give `AlbumView.Cover` a default value. And then in the `Loaded` event of my `GridViewItem`, I call the `FindThumbnail()`.

```
    private void DropShadowControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as AlbumView)?.FindThumbnail();
    }
```

More source code is [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/AlbumsPage.xaml.cs).

I stop getting crash now, but there seems to be a problem with this. Every single `DropShadowControl` should have a corresponding `AlbumView` but I get `null` sometimes. And I think this might be a cause for my further problem, which is most of my `DropShadowControl`s are still showing the default image after they have been loaded. However, after I redirect back to the `AlbumsPage`, those thumbnails are displayed correctly.

And I have set the binding of `Cover` to be `OneWay`, which you can see from [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/DropShadowControl.xaml).

What's my problem?

Comment: Hi, you can monitor the memory usage status during debug. Check if it is a gradual increase in the final crash, and if so, please minimize the IO and other operations that take up large system resources. For example, instead of looking for thumbnails on a file-by-file basis, you can point the thumbnail property to an existing image (such as `music.thumbnail="ms-appx:///Assets/Thumbnail.png"`). Will greatly reduce the number of file IO.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT But I need them eventually, why would that be a reduction of IO?

Comment: Hi, I understand that you need thumbnails, but the thumbnails of the music files look the same (a note icon). If you really need to read the thumbnails, you can also use `Binding`+`Converter` to read the image after the UI is created, instead of using asynchronous to read the file during the creation of the instance. If you just set a URI for image, but don't read it through Stream, there is no significant impact on performance during the construction of an instance of the class.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT I got what you mean. Actually I am not using the default system music thumbnails. I am using distinct album cover images. So I don't think it is possible to get the uri. You can see more how I got those thumbnails [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Helpers/Helper.cs) around the function `GetStorageItemThumbnailAsync`.

Comment: Hi, It can be seen that this is a performance issue. You need to start optimizing your application in some ways, and we can't modify your code directly at this point. You can consider: 1. If you don't need a picture as large as 500px, please lower the resolution of the picture. 2. Minimize the number of file IOs. 3. Use [lazy loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-deferloadstrategy-attribute) to reduce the burden on the UI. [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/planning-and-measuring-performance) may help you

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT Lazy loading is what I am thinking of. I just don't know if the crash was caused by the frequent IO. I just confirmed that by comment out `FindThumbnail`. I think the strategy in the link you provided might not fit my case well but I have thought of another solution. Thanks!

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT I have found an issue with my lazy load strategy and I have updated my question. Could you please take a look at it?

Comment: Hi, For your later question, I suggest you write the Loaded method inside the DropShadowPanel class, because this looks like a load order problem.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT That doesn't help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201539/discussion-between-richard-zhang-msft-and-seaky).

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT I have joined the chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some attempts, I have found out that my initial problem is due to the frequent IO operations.

So to avoid that I need to do lazy loading.

The problem with my previous loading strategy mentioned in the updated question, putting things in the `Loaded` event, is not good because if my `DropShadowControl` is not visible, even though it is loaded, it will have a `null DataContext`. And I rely on that to find the thumbnail.

So I need an when-my-control-become-visible-and-datacontext-available event, which is `DataContextChanged`.

By putting code in that function/event instead of `Loaded`, my problem is solved perfectly.